# how to change a 1*1 matrix in Eigen to float?

Tags: matrix, eigen

I'm using eigen matrix library.

How can I convert a matrix of 1* 1 to a number(float or others)?

It's OK to do this

```
cout << ((MatrixXf(1,2) << 0, 2).finished()) * ((MatrixXf(2,1) << 0, 2).finished()) << endl;
```

But when I try to do this

```
MatrixXf mtemp(2,1);
mtemp(0,0) = ((MatrixXf(1,2) << 0, 2).finished()) * ((MatrixXf(2,1) << 0, 2).finished());
```

It said 'cannot convert const Eigen::GeneralProduct to float in assignment'.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If `mat` is an 1-by-1 matrix, then `mat.value()` is its only entry as a scalar.

Thus, you can do

```
mtemp(0,0) = (((MatrixXf(1,2) << 0, 2).finished()) 
              * ((MatrixXf(2,1) << 0, 2).finished())).value();
```

Comment: https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/classEigen_1_1DenseBase.html#a8515f719046aa4851e385661f45595b0 doc page for `.value()` because searching for `Eigen value` is not productive :-)

Comment: I guess `.value()` is syntactic "sugar" for `(0,0)`? Not sure it's actually more readable than `(0,0)` though.

Comment: This might be wrong, but perhaps using `.value()` instead of `(0,0)` makes it easier for the compiler to optimize. `(0,0)` is known at runtime, `.value()` at compile

Comment: I'm pretty sure if the matrix is known to be 1x1 at compile time then (0,0) will be known (and hopefully treated the same)